# Python - clever way to define filenames including string and number suffix, in order to sort them properly later

Tags: python, sorting, filenames

I am looking for a clever way to sort my files in Python.

I am generating many JSON files in a folder which includes a string and index.
Currently I can list them like:

```
[A_0.json, A_1.json, A_2.json, A_3.json ... A_500.json]
```

Another folder contains:

```
[B_0.json, B_1.json, B_2.json, B_3.json ... B_300.json]
```

In the next step, for each folder, I will run a script to merge all files into one.
So, I would like to keep this naming convention (string + index).
The suffix numbers come from index from Dataframe.

But, I am struggling to merge all JSON files into one with the right sequence of the index. I first sorted files in a folder:

```
['A_0.json', 'A_1.json', 'A_10.json', 'A_100.json', 'A_101.json', 'A_2.json', 'A_3.json']
```

What I would like to see is:

```
['A_0.json', 'A_1.json', 'A_2.json', 'A_3.json', 'A_10.json', 'A_100.json', 'A_101.json'...]
```

So, the merged file can contain the content of JSON files in the right order. Note: the original JSON files should be preserved. Sorry that this question may mean two questions/steps.

Suggestion to solve this problem is appreciated. If your suggestion requires the slight change of the naming convention, that is not ideal, but I would definitely consider. Many thanks!

Comment: it is not clear if you want to sort them in the desired way or if the question is how to keep the index when they are not sorted.

Comment: your problem is that python sorts alphabetically and you want numerical sort. Easiest way would be to pad your numbers so they sort alphabetically ("A_001" sorts before "A_010"). If you can't, you'll have to pass a lambda to `sort` that will split and return something sortable.

Comment: I think to make 2 digits 3 digits is a nice alternative. Code gets a couple of lines more than originally is. It is preferred that I dont have to manipulate the index from Dataframe, but thanks for an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that integer 1 comes before 2 and 2 before 11, but since its a string its handled as if its an alphabetical character: "a" comes before "aa" and only then comes "ba".

Since you want to sort alphabetical and also numerical, you have 2 different sort orders you want to apply.

Therfore you need to separate the string from the integer and apply the sorting separately, like so:

```
import re

def alphanumeric_sort(lst):

    def convert(text):
        return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

    def alphanum_key(key):
        return [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]

    return sorted(lst, key=alphanum_key)

your_list = ['A_0.json', 'A_1.json', 'A_10.json', 'A_100.json', 'A_101.json', 'A_2.json', 'A_3.json']
alphanumeric_sort(your_list)
```

---

If you don't mind non-standard imports/libraries you can also use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
from natsort import natsorted

your_list = ['A_0.json', 'A_1.json', 'A_10.json', 'A_100.json', 'A_101.json', 'A_2.json', 'A_3.json']
natsorted(your_list )
```

Comment: natsort works well. Very interesting and easy tool. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Please try

> l = ['A_0.json', 'A_1.json', 'A_10.json', 'A_100.json', 'A_101.json', A_2.json', 'A_99.json']
>
> l.sort(key=len)
>
> print(l)`

Comment: Unfortunately the length is not the criteria to sort in my case.

Comment: I can see it. But it will fix yours. Simple. If you wish you can use. I use this to arrange pdf pages of book having 1000 pages. Where have same  naming problem